# Is there a way to make an HTML tab container fix its height to that of its tallest tab?

Tags: html, css, tabs, height

I have a tab container that hides `<div>` containers with CSS and makes one visible with JavaScript depending on the currently selected tab (based on [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
 line-height: 1.6
}

.container {
 width: 600px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

ul.tabs {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
 background: none;
 color: #222;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
 background: #ededed;
 color: #222;
}

.tab-content {
 display: none;
 background: #ededed;
 padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
 display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 </div>
 <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </div>
 <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
 </div>
 <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
  Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the size of the tab container (shown as a `1px solid black` line in the example above) to remain fixed, and large enough to contain its tallest tab even when the tallest tab is not selected. Can this be done in a way that it uses the real content size, rather than some fixed CSS width/height, and without using JavaScript to compute the height after page load?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found is using relatively new [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). Just put every tab content into the same grid cell like this:

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "content";
}

.tab-content {
  grid-area: content;
}
```

Then set `visibility: hidden` to hide tabs but keep space for them in layout.

A modified version of the given example [can be found here](https://codepen.io/kalabukdima/pen/xxGgdvy).

Answer (score 0):

Give your "tab-content" div a proper height like 100-200px and make overflow scroll-able.

```
.tab-content{
        display: none;
        height:100px;
        background: #ededed;
        padding: 15px;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is something I asked in my question about avoiding. Ideally I'd like a solution that doesn't involve setting a fixed, explicit height via CSS, but rather one that will calculate the height of the container to fit the largest tab.