# How do I set HTML tabs height based on content of the most full tab without using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am working with a Learning Management System that has the ability to inject custom html, css and javascript.

I've put together a tabbed content template that works in the constraints of the LMS by cribbing together various examples on CodePen.

I am looking for a way to automatically set the height of all of the tabs based on the height of the tab with the most content.

I've found an example in a SO answer which does what I want:

[Is there a way to make an HTML tab container fix its height to that of its tallest tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060270/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-html-tab-container-fix-its-height-to-that-of-its-talle)

In theory, this is great - but the restrictions of the LMS mean that I can't import external scripts, e.g. jQuery. So it won't work on the LMS.

This example also works, but uses jQuery and Bootstrap:

https://observablehq.com/@rkaravia/css-trick-tabs-with-consistent-height

Is there any way of doing this entirely with html, CSS and JS? And not using jQuery, Bootstrap etc? If not, I will just set a fixed height and set the overflow so that is scrolls within the container (not ideal).

Comment: You may use a grid layout and set every tab inside the same cell so the tallest gives the height for the whole tabcontainer. here is a working example (HTML/CSS  no js)  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdoQWKP ... if that was you looked for. **Note** you should provide your code to show your issue and attempts . Welcome on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example you provided only uses css and html and some bootstrap styling.

Nothing complicated here. You just make the container with `overflow: hidden` and also `display: flex` that they are in one row

And then for the inactive ones, set `visibility: hidden` and `margin-left: -100%` so that they go beyond the container and at the same time maintain the size.

For example [on codepan](https://codepen.io/stevedekart/pen/bGZQWpv)

Comment: Thank you. That is so much neater than what I was working on, which involved using JS to find all the hidden elements, clone them and calculate the height if they were rendered. Which I just got working, but it is very clunky. That example is very useful.